# Time complexity of binary tree traversal( pre order)

Tags: data-structures, big-o

```
        PreorderTraversal(root)----T(n)
        {
          //Base case
          If(root equals null)-------------------O(1)
             return errormsg; ------------------O(1)
         else
             print root;---------------------------------O(1)
            //Recursive case
            PreorderTraversal(root.left);--T(n/2)
           PreorderTraversal(root.right)-T(n/2);
         }
```

Time complexity calculated based on back substitution method

Base case  assumed as 1

```
        T(1)=O(1)
        T(n) = O(1)+T(n/2)
        T(n/2)=O(1)+T(n/4)
        T(n/4)=O(1)+T(n/8)
        T(n)=1+T(n/2)
               =1+1+T(n/4)
               =2+T(n/4)
               =2+1+T(n/8)
               =3+T(n/8)
        Pattern follws like
              = K+T(n/2^k).     I.e. n/2^k =1
                                             n = 2^k
                                             K= logn
              =log n + 1
              =log n
```

In my understanding time complexity of binary tree(pre order traversal) is log n most of them said time complexity of binary tree(pre order) is
    O(n)

I don't know which one is correct??

Kindly guide me for above issue??

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity for pre-order traversal is O(n) because you visit each node only once.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get `T(n)=log(n)` is that your equation for complexity is incorrect.
It should be `T(n)=O(1)+2T(n/2)` (because you are applying the same algorithm for the left and the right child). And this will be the case only when the tree is balanced, if the tree is linear then you would have `T(n)=O(1)+T(n-1)` which will give you clearly a linear time. Also the first case will give you a linear time. By applying your method you would get `T(n) = O(2^k * T(1))` where `k = log(n)` so `T(n)=O(n)`.

To make it easy to compute time complexity just imagine what the algorithm does, here the preorder will visit all the nodes, and each node only once, so it is intuitive that is O(n) time complexity

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question today. Your equation is slightly wrong. That's why you're getting log(n) complexity.

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) = 2T(n/2) //equation 1
T(1) = O(1) //base case
T(n/2) = T(n/4) + T(n/4) = 2T(n/4) //equation 2
```

On solving them, we get,

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) 
T(n) = 2*2(T(n/4)) = 4(T(n/4))
T(n) = 2^k * T(n/2^k) //equation 3
```

On solving for the value of k, we get,

```
n/2^k = 1
n = 2^k
log n = k
```

On using the value of k in equation 3, we get,

```
T(n) = 2^logn * T(1) // 2^logn is n.
T(n) = O(n) * O(1)
T(n) = O(n)
```

And that is how you get O(n) time complexity.

Comment: wh 2^logn is n ?

Comment: `2^log(n) = n` -To prove it, apply log to both sides. It would be equal to `log(n) = log(n)`. Because `log(2^log(n) = log(n) * log(2)` and `log(2) = 1`.